# foreach controller printing only default value in jmeter

Tags: foreach, jmeter

I am new to jmeter. I want to do performance testing. My problem is when I mpassing value from one http req to another http request which is in foreach in controller that request running for default value only it's not picking regex values.I m using jmeter 2.13

here is my regular expression extractor
ref name=names

```
regex=(dentist|ortho|cardio)
template=$1$
match no=-1
default=none

**first http req**
IP-localhost port=8080

path=JmeterJson/speciality

**second req**

IP-localhost port=8080

path=JmeterJson/names?speciality={names}


FOREACH CONTROLLER 
I/P name=names
o/p name=name
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the following variables in order to make ForEach Controller work:

```
names_1=dentist
names_2=ortho
names_3=cardio
```

Use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) combination to check it.

Evidence:

[image: For Each Controller]

Example Test Plan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.8" jmeter="2.13 r1665067">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1455215406000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1455215406000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <BeanShellSampler guiclass="BeanShellSamplerGui" testclass="BeanShellSampler" testname="BeanShell Sampler" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.query">return &quot;dentist ortho cardio&quot;</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.filename"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.parameters"></stringProp>
          <boolProp name="BeanShellSampler.resetInterpreter">false</boolProp>
        </BeanShellSampler>
        <hashTree>
          <RegexExtractor guiclass="RegexExtractorGui" testclass="RegexExtractor" testname="Regular Expression Extractor" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.useHeaders">false</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.refname">names</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">(dentist|ortho|cardio)</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.template">$1$</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.default"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.match_number">-1</stringProp>
          </RegexExtractor>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <DebugSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugSampler" testname="Debug Sampler" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
        </DebugSampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <ForeachController guiclass="ForeachControlPanel" testclass="ForeachController" testname="ForEach Controller" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="ForeachController.inputVal">names</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="ForeachController.returnVal">name</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="ForeachController.useSeparator">true</boolProp>
        </ForeachController>
        <hashTree>
          <BeanShellSampler guiclass="BeanShellSamplerGui" testclass="BeanShellSampler" testname="${name}" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.query"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.filename"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.parameters"></stringProp>
            <boolProp name="BeanShellSampler.resetInterpreter">false</boolProp>
          </BeanShellSampler>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Reference material: [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

Comment: hi,thanks for your quick reply. plz can u tell me how to give variables name there in controller?? It won't generate automatically when foreach controller runs?

Comment: I tried to give input name as "names_" but now controller not running.which variable and where I have to give name like names_1??

Comment: do I have to give user define variables?

Comment: My response data:                          SamplerProperties:
HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST=false
HTTPSampler.auto_redirects=false


JMeterVariables:
JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true
JMeterThread.pack=org.apache.jmeter.threads.SamplePackage@3bea6f1d
START.HMS=110208
START.MS=1455168728720
START.YMD=20160211
TESTSTART.MS=1455254369824
names=NONE
names_1=cardio
names_1_g=1
names_1_g0=cardio
names_1_g1=cardio
names_2=dentist
names_2_g=1
names_2_g0=dentist
names_2_g1=dentist
names_matchNr=2

Comment: Thank you very much sir previously that evidence link was not opening due to some issues. now I saw it. I m very grateful for this..:)

Comment: but sir link is generated but data is not printing yet..still data is NONE only.:(

Comment: Hi, Thank u. I had to use same o/p name in next request..:)